# Get id token from the access token

Tags: azure-active-directory

I use angular with spring boot

Actually angular app send me the bearer token (access token) to the spring boot (backend end).

With this token is it possible to get the id token?

Answer (score 2):

To get ID token along with access token, you need to pass **`openid`** as the scope.

Grant **`openid`** permission to the Microsoft Entra application:

[image]

**To get ID token along with access token,** modify your code by passing scope as **`openid`**

```js
scope:  'api://<<<client_id>>>/app openid',
```

For ***sample***, I tried to generate tokens via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://xxx/api.access openid
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secretClientSecret
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Securing Angular and Spring Boot applications with Azure AD - Jeroen Meys — Ordina JWorks Tech Blog (ordina-jworks.io)](https://blog.ordina-jworks.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html) by *Jeroen Meys*